# Multiple Database SQL server Connections on Laravel 5.4 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

[image: error image]

Inside of my database configuration file - likely app/config/database.php.

```
 'connections' => [

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.0.5'),//'ADMINRG-2UH26BG', // Provide IP address here
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'VHPDEV'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'Dbp@2013'),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
        'sqlsrv2' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.0.5'),//'ADMINRG-2UH26BG', // Provide IP address here
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'OCSDB'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'Dbp@2013'),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=192.168.0.5
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=VHPDEV
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=Dbp@2013
```

**Query**

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('B14SILHOLD')->get();
```

Comment: Make you have a table named ```B14SILHOLD```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just clear cache of laravel by running command such as:- php artisan config:cache and try to execute it.
Also remember that check that your DB is defined in your model where you are using it or just put \DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('B14SILHOLD')->get();